# simplifying Boolean expression A'BC + AB'C + A'B'C' + AB'C + ABC

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Need help here, whats the simplified form of this Boolean expression?
I'm a little confused about this, help me guys!

```
A'BC + AB'C + A'B'C' + AB'C + ABC
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplifying Boolean Expression (A'BC) + (A'B'C) + (A'BC) + (AB'C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861329/simplifying-boolean-expression-abc-abc-abc-abc)

Comment: Use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=not+A+and+B+and+C+or+A+and+not+B+and+C+or+not+A+and+not+B+and+not+C+or+A+and+not+B+and+C+or+A+and+B+and+C) as a guide.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the ⋅ operator represents binary conjunction, the + binary disjunction and the ' or the ¬ unary negation, **you can apply the laws of [Boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)**:

```
¬a⋅b⋅c + a⋅¬b⋅c + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c + a⋅¬b⋅c + a⋅b⋅c
¬a⋅b⋅c + a⋅¬b⋅c + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c + a⋅b⋅c //idempotence of +: a⋅¬b⋅c + a⋅¬b⋅c = a⋅¬b⋅c
b⋅c⋅(¬a + a) + a⋅¬b⋅c + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c  //distributivity:¬a⋅b⋅c + a⋅b⋅c = b⋅c⋅(¬a + a)
b⋅c⋅(1) + a⋅¬b⋅c + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c       //complementation: ¬a + a = 1
b⋅c + a⋅¬b⋅c + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c           //identity for ⋅: b⋅c⋅(1) = b⋅c
b⋅c + a⋅b⋅c + a⋅¬b⋅c + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c   //absorption: b⋅c = b⋅c + a⋅b⋅c
b⋅c + a⋅c⋅(b + ¬b) + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c     //distributivity: a⋅b⋅c + a⋅¬b⋅c = a⋅c⋅(b + ¬b)
b⋅c + a⋅c⋅(1) + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c          //complementation: b + ¬b = 1

b⋅c + a⋅c + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c              //identity for ⋅: a⋅c⋅(1) = a⋅c
```

The final line is the original expression's minimal DNF. You can also transform it to it's minimal CNF:

```
b⋅c + a⋅c + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c
(b⋅c + a⋅c) + (¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c)
((b⋅c + a⋅c) + ¬a)⋅((b⋅c + a⋅c) + ¬b)⋅((b⋅c + a⋅c) + ¬c)  //distributivity
(b⋅c + a⋅c + ¬a) ⋅ (b⋅c + a⋅c + ¬b) ⋅ (b⋅c + a⋅c + ¬c)
(b⋅c + c + ¬a)  ⋅  (b⋅c + a⋅c + ¬b) ⋅ (b⋅c + a⋅c + ¬c)    //absorption
(b⋅c + c + ¬a)  ⋅  (c + a⋅c + ¬b)   ⋅ (b⋅c + a⋅c + ¬c)    //absorption
(b⋅c + c + ¬a)  ⋅  (c + a⋅c + ¬b)   ⋅ (b + a + ¬c)        //absorption
(c + ¬a)        ⋅  (c + a⋅c + ¬b)   ⋅ (b + a + ¬c)        //absorption
(c + ¬a)        ⋅  (c + ¬b)         ⋅ (b + a + ¬c)        //absorption

(¬a + c)⋅(¬b + c)⋅(a + b + ¬c)
```

**For this small number of variables, you can also use Karnaugh maps.** In the picture (generated using latex) you can see marked out **three equivalent expressions** – the original one, it's minimal DNF and it's minimal CNF:

[image: Three equivalent expressions in the K-maps]

```
f(a,b,c) = ¬a⋅b⋅c + a⋅¬b⋅c + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c + a⋅b⋅c
         = b⋅c + a⋅c + ¬a⋅¬b⋅¬c
         = (¬a + c)⋅(¬b + c)⋅(a + b + ¬c)
```